# Magento 2 category saving error related to category product assignment

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento2

## **this is what happening with the store i´m building: I have 280k products to import, i´m doing it in with 7 csv files every file contains 40k of data except the last one.**

### My problem is the following:

I import the first 40k of data with all the attributes i need, then when the import process is complete i can´t save the categories where the products are assigned.

A thing i want to do is just to create one url for my product bcause when i upload a product for both categories,

i.e: ***category-parent,category-parent/category-child*** the system creates two url for both categories like this: **category-parent/my-product** and **category-parent/category-child/my-product**, what i want is this: **category-parent/category-child/my-product**

Even if i choose to enable canonical url for categories, it keeps creating three urls:

.One for **category-parent**

.Another for **category-parent/category-child**

**for 40k products the url-rewrites reaches to 119.**

right now i´m deleting everything from the store to re import the products and see what´s happening with this issue.

All the help i can get will be much appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: are you using magento default import? take a look into this Magmi(http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113533/magmi-alternative-for-magento-2-0) it will import product faster as compared to magento.

Comment: Yes @ManojChaurasia i´m using Magento Default import, it´s even more slow to delete 40k products.

Comment: you can go with magmi tool, it is preety fast as compared with magento default.